# Django throws AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta' when I register my Model

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I`m novice and I didn`t find solution for this problem.
I`m writing code for a blog. I have a model Post where I want to create field author which is ForeighKey to User. If I make migration without admin.site.register - everything is ok. But then I`m trying to register my Model to Django admin it throws AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

Comment: my idea is that every user (after registration) can create post. And I want to show some information about author using User model

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Автор', related_name='posts', null=True)
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name='Заголовок объявления', max_length=255)
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name='Текст объявления')
    CATEGORIES = (
        ('T','Танки'),
        ('HM','Хилы'),
        ('DD','ДД'),
        ('TrM','Торговцы'),
        ('GM','Гилдмастеры'),
        ('QG','Квестгиверы'),
        ('FM','Кузнецы'),
        ('LM','Кожевники'),
        ('PM','Зельевары'),
        ('WM','Мастера заклинаний')
    )

    category = models.CharField(verbose_name='Категория', max_length=3, choices=CATEGORIES)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Дата создания')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Пост'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Посты'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *

admin.site.register('Post')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a reference to the class, not a string literal, so:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from app_name.models import Post

admin.site.register(Post)
```

where you replace *`app_name`* with the name of the app where you defined the `Post` model.

---

> **Note**: Please do [*not* use wildcard imports [quantifiedcode.com]](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/maintainability/from_module_import_all_used.html).
> It makes the statement less predictable, it can easily result in failing code if you later decide to change what is exported in a certain module, and
> furthermore it can override variables.

Comment: Actually it doesn`t help. I still have same trouble.

Comment: @Sobbaka: you did not use `.register(Post)`, but `.register('Post')`, you thus should *not* sue a string literal, but a reference to the class.

Comment: My apologies! You are absolutely right. Trouble was with 'punctuation'